# Creating dynamic HTML hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, python, html

Using a list of genes which I have created in a python script, I am trying to create clickable links for each gene in the list.  I am using the Flask framework to accomplish this and am able to access the genes in my list with the {{genes}} variable.  I am able to see this list when I view the page source, but when I try to add each gene to the body of my DOM with a javascript function I don't see anything.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>Genes<h1>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

    </head>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    function showGenes(){

        var name = "";
        for (gene in {{genes}}) {
            var name = document.createElement('a');
            var text = document.createTextNode(name);
            name.appendChild(text);
            document.body.appendChild(name);

        }

}
    </script>

<body onload="showGenes()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Why tagged as Python?

Comment: Why do you need javascript for creating HTML? Since you are using some templating language already, create thr HTML on the templating level. downvoted..

Comment: It is tagged as python since I am using python's flask framework to generate the gene list.  I am not sure how to create the html from the template language, or if it can be done with flask.  I know it can be done with javascript, and that's why I asked this question.  So how do I do it within the question that I posted?

Comment: every python web framework give you the option passing a list or a dict or whatever data to your template and use it for rendering.

Comment: And you "only" know that it can be done with Javascript and you have zero idea about using a Python webframework properly. Read the Flask documentation and check how you can do loops. But doing this in Javascript is nonsense.

Comment: Don't put a h1 in the head, nor a script between the head and the body. Also, don't use two different variables with the same name. This causes confusion, because the name name is the same name as the name name.

Comment: Could you please post the content of genes? It needs to be a valid json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `{{genes}}` is a **javascript** array, you need to replace your loop the following way (Just remember, it is javascript, not python, so you cannot use for - in loop that easily):

```
$.each({{genes}}, function(index, value){
     $('body').append($('<a></a>').text(value));
 })
```